# installing wordpress on xampp errors

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, xampp

I have installed XAMPP for Windows 5.5.35 on my local machine and have copied wordpress 4.5.2 in the htdocs/sass-wp folder.
the error I am getting is:

> Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\sass-wp/wp-includes/load.php): failed to   open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\sass-wp\wp-settings.php on line 21
>   Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\sass-wp/wp-includes/load.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\sass-wp\wp-settings.php on line 21

I have looked at the following question on stackoverflow:
*[PHP - Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory/36577021#36577021)*
which indicates that my problem is to do with paths, relative and absolute.
As I am a beginner with PHP and xampp I am not sure where to apply the fixes.

Here is the code on line 21

```
define( 'WPINC', 'wp-includes' );
// Include files required for initialization.
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/load.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/default-constants.php' );
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

the Xampp 5.5.35 has PHP version 5.5.35, Wordpress 4.5.2 require PHP 5.6 or greater

Comment: I have updated to PHP and still had the same problem so have re-installed xamp which now gives me a denied access. thanks for the tip about the version of php to use with this version of wp

Comment: you can still try to troubleshoot your issue with denied access using the same link that you looked at